# I have a 2001 gsxr 750 bogging down between 7000 and 9000 rpm but good before and after that?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, gsxr

I've got a 2001 GSXR 750 bogs down between 7 and 9000 RPM but anything before and after that it runs great... ive got new stator new injectors ,new coils and new fuel pump and filter. oh and new secondary throttle valve that is set and adjusted to spec to put out the correct voltage to the ecm .. Any help on this would be GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: If there are any engine/exhaust mods, the fuel map may be off,

Comment: It sounds like a fueling problem. Was the ECM ever programmed or fiddled with?